# DataGridView filter hiding edited items

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which is bound to a DataTable. This is then filtered on 2 columns, using the below code, however when you edit either one of the cells in the filtered columns and then click on another row (or anywhere else within the form) the edited row disappears because of the filter.

```
string rowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] = '{1}'", "Assigned To", comboBoxDepartment.Text);
rowFilter += string.Format(" AND [{0}] = '{1}'", "Status", comboBoxCaseStatus.Text);
(dataGridViewCases.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = rowFilter;
```

How can I stop this from happening when editing one of the filtered fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'll assume you have an ID column which is unique)

You must declare your filter outside any method.

```
string filter;
```

declare these too:

```
int id;        
string nameOfcolumn;
string newValue;
```

Apply your filter as you originally did, but now the filter is declared outside the method.

In the cell DataGridView_CellParsing event method you get the value of the cell  after being edited, but you get it before the filter is applied, in this event method you must save the id of the row being modified:

```
private void DataGridView_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
    {
    //Get the id, (assuming that the id is in the first column)
    id =int.Parse(DataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

    //If you need more comparison, you can get the name of the column and the new value of the cell too         
     nameOfcolumn = DataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
     newValue = e.Value.ToString();
    }
```

Now on the DataGridView_CellEndEdit event method you will modify your filter and reapply it.

```
private void DataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        filter += " OR id=" + id.ToString(); //The modified value is now being included on the filter



   //If you need more comparisons or if you can't use an id, you can use columnName and newValue        

   //filter += " OR (" + columnName + " LIKE '" + newValue+ "' AND id=" + id.ToString() + ")";


  //Re-apply it 
        (DataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter=filter;  
  }
```

I took the idea from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102819/suppress-or-cancel-filter-on-datagridview-edit?rq=1), but there's the complain that the first answer "shows also all other rows which have similar values for that column", but you solve it if you use the ID.

Comment: Thanks with a few edits this was exactly what I needed.